# .nano_history permissions error

Tags: permissions, nano

I use `rkhunter` and I was wanting to check its logs with:

```
nano /var/log/rkhunter.log
```

But `nano` outputted this error:

```
Error reading /home/arthur-dent/.nano_history: Permission denied

Press Enter to continue starting nano.
```

And if I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> I am able to view the file. I have checked the permissions for that file and they are now:

```
-rw-------   1 root        root           12 May  3 20:26 .nano_history
```

So I guess that I just change ownership back to me? But as I was literally just using `nano`, why would the permissions and ownership (possibly, as I do not know what the original ownership was) just suddenly change? Was it because I was just using it with `sudo`, if so, it is odd as nothing like this has ever happend before and I use `sudo` with it a lot?

---

### OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

### Package Information:

```
nano:
  Installed: 2.2.6-3
  Candidate: 2.2.6-3
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.6-3 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Interesting. Mine says `-rw------- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 31 May  3 13:51 .nano_history`

Comment: /var/log/ needs sudo so the nano command might error out on that.

Comment: @Rinzwind so you're saying, if  one views a file as `nano /var/log/somelog`,  with permissions 600 (and without sudo ), `.nano_history` changes ownership to root ? I did that just now with `atop` log, and my `.nano_history` file is still the same

Comment: Thats interesting..if it were a graphical application, this could be caused if you run `sudo nano` instead of `gksudo nano`....on a different note, don't parse log files using editors, use `tail`/`less`/`more` -like tools..

Comment: @Serg nope. I aint saying that. This happens when you use root with nautilus and change a file as root. And I agree with heemayl What is the idea of using an editor on a log?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is possible if `.nano_history` does not exist and you edit any file as root. Start a search action with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and `.nano_history` has the wrong ownership.

```
sudo chown arthur-dent:arthur-dent /home/arthur-dent/.nano_history
```

Later, the ownership of the file will not be changed.

I've tested:

```
% ls -l .nano_history
ls: cannot access .nano_history: No such file or directory

% sudo nano ~/tmp/<any_file>
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Search anything.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

```
% ls -l .nano_history
-rw------- 1 root root 6 Mai  3 22:08 .nano_history

% sudo chown aboettger:aboettger .nano_history
% ls -l .nano_history                    
-rw------- 1 aboettger aboettger 6 Mai  3 22:08 .nano_history

% sudo nano ~/tmp/<any_file>
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Search anything.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

```
% ls -l .nano_history  
-rw------- 1 aboettger aboettger 11 Mai  3 22:11 .nano_history
```

Comment: Removed my `.nano_history` and opened `sudo nano /var/log/syslog`, searched through it, and `.nano_history` was created as root. So, yeah, this does happen. However, if a file existed previously, it doesn't seem to change ownership to root. I've tried going through syslog again after chmoding my .nano_history, and that one is still owned by me

Answer (score 9):

This can happen when you don't own the .nano_history file that's normally contained inside your home directory. This happened to me when I ran nano for the first time on my Ubuntu install along with sudo. This meant that .nano_history was owned by root and not readable unless sudo was used with nano each time. When it wasn't used, nano complained on startup with 'Permission denied'. Copy and paste this exactly into your terminal to fix the issue:

```
sudo chown $USER:$(id -gn) $HOME/.nano_history
```